# Making requests to views always running asynchronously in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, asynchronous, instagram-api

I'm currently using [this](https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python) API to make requests to Instagram. However. every time I need to pull info from the API, I'm required to sign into an account, which takes an extra 3 or 4 seconds.

In order to make this process more efficient, and not to mention experience login throttling from Insta, I'd like a view that keeps the account logged in.

Is this possible with a single server?